# Bootstrap grid system works strangely

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code :

```
<div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 ">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
            <div class="forget"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body" >
            <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
            <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- id / pw -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                            <div class="row">
                                <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12"> Login</a>
                                <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Login with Facebook</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                        <div class="signup">
                            Don't have an account?
                            <a href="#" id="signuplink">
                                Sign Up Here
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>  <!-- <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" > -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing that I changed is `<div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 ">`

And here is before/after : 
[image]
[image]

Before I inserted `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`, the blue-shaded box looks balanced.
After I inserted `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`, it looks unbalanced.

Why does it happen? I think that grid should work well(login box should be located at center" because it means `3(offset) - 6 - 3(offset)'.

Need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your loginbox does not have 12 columns in total as you specified 6+3(offset) =9

I would suggest this way as I dont like using offset

```
<div class="col-md-3 "></div>
<div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
            <div class="forget"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body" >
            <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
            <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- id / pw -->
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                            <div class="row">
                                <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12"> Login</a>
                                <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Login with Facebook</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                        <div class="signup">
                            Don't have an account?
                            <a href="#" id="signuplink">
                                Sign Up Here
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>  <!-- <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" > -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 "></div>
```

Comment: Wow! this is awesome! I am not gonna use `offset` from now on, either

Comment: Hey, `loginbox` is located at center, but class `panel` isn't located at center of `loginbox`...?

Comment: @user3595632 was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take: giving it a fluid container and a couple extra rows to center things up:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="brown-row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
              <div class="forget"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
              <div id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
              <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <!-- id / pw -->
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                  <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                  <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <!-- Button -->
                  <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                    <div class="row">
                      <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12"> Login</a>
                      <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>Login with Facebook</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-12 control">
                    <div class="signup">
                      Don't have an account?
                      <a href="#" id="signuplink">
                                Sign Up Here
                            </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <!-- <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" > -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
body {
  background: #634a16;
}
.brown-row {
  background: #9e7623;
}
#loginbox {
  margin-top: 50px
}
```